# Firebase will not let me create service account key

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

When trying to generate and download a new service account key I get a message that I have reached my limit. I don't have any keys created so it seems the limit is 0.

I am using a Google Workspace account. I believe that this setting is being limited by the organization that the gmail account is associated with. There is only one email for the organization which I am using and it is the adminstrator. I have the ability to change any Google Cloud setting but I have no idea where to go and do this.

The main reason why I mention Workspace is that it's only happening on this new account with a new Workspace domain and a fresh Firebase install. I spun up a quick Firebase project with a gmail account and did not have an issue with keys at all.

I need a key so that I can create a node.js program that sets custom claims on authenticated users.

[image: firebase issue]

[image: What I saw in Google Cloud]

Doug Stevenson: Even though the message says you have reached the limit it doesn't make sense because I don't have any keys created.

Also, here is what happens when the steps you provided are followed.

Click the Add key drop-down menu, then select Create new key.
[image]
Select JSON as the Key type and click Create.
[image]

I found a place to edit organizational constraints however it appears here that the disableServiceAccountCreation is not enforced.
https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/orgpolicies
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you see an error message, it's a good idea to start with a web search using the exact text.  That's how I found the instructions.

Comment: 1) A service account can have a maximum of 10 keys [reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete#creating). 2) If you are trying to exceed the max, you have three choices: a) purge a key, reuse an existing key, or create a new service account and key. 3) Be cautious of service account key sprawl. That is a quick way to lose track of keys. That also affects the principal recorded in the audit logs. For each use case, a best practice is to create a service account with one key. 4) I recommend consulting with your organization's IAM admin.

Comment: Another question. Why do you need to create a service account key for Functions? Use the built-in features to assign a service account to the Function. That feature removes the requirement for a service account key. Edit your question to explain why you need a key. There might be other solutions.

Comment: Why does your question title have "Workspace Gmail account" in the title? Workspace is not part of your problem or solution.

Comment: Hi John, I did not communicate clearly in my question. I said I had multiple keys. I feel pretty foolish to admit this but what I have is multiple service accounts. I don't have any keys. I cannot create one either through Firebase UI or google cloud UI. the main reason why I mention workspace is that it's only happening on this new account with a new workspace domain and a fresh firebase install. I spun up a quick firebase project with a gmail account and did not have an issue with keys at all. I will edit the questions to include why I need a key.

Comment: I have edited the title and made adjustments to the content of the question. I hope it's more clear now. If you have time to look at again I would truly appreicate it. TY.

Answer (score 1):

You should review the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete#deleting).  The instructions for doing this in the google cloud console are are spelled out clearly:

> 1. In the Google Cloud console, go to the Service accounts page. Go to "Service accounts". The remaining steps will appear automatically in
>    the Google Cloud console.
> 2. Select a project.
> 3. On the Service accounts page, click the email address of the service account whose key you want to delete.
> 4. Click the Keys tab.
> 5. From the list of keys, click Delete delete for each key you'd like to delete.

It will be entirely up to you to figure out which key to delete, as this might have effects on the way you might already be using this service account.

Comment: Hello Doug I do appreciate your answer. I should have identified that the error message doesn't make sense. Deleting a few or all keys will not fix this issue. If you look at the second image it appears that it's a permission issue and not a limit issue.

Even though the message says you have reached the limit this is not the real issue. I have two projects one development and one production. Each with a different amount of keys. This is under this one account. One with 5 one with 10. I have other Firebase projects not under this account with 15 keys. Never has there been a limit issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are not looking at the correct org policy

```
Disable service account creation

Disable service account key creation
```

You were looking at SA creation not key creation